# theos springboard

Tags: jailbreak, tweak, theos

Does anyone have this experience?

I just follow the http://brandontreb.com/beginning-jailbroken-ios-development-your-first-tweak/, however every make command ends up like: no springboard/springboard.h file or directory. How to solve this?

One more thing, can anyone give me download link for **Saurik's libsubstrate.dylib dynamic library** ? I did a lot search and found nothing.

Thanks so much for any advice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **SpringBoard headers** from rpetrich's repository from here https://github.com/rpetrich/iphoneheaders

Download these **headers** and put them in /var/theos/include. (If you're developing on your iDevice). Then type #import `<SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h>`in your tweak.xm at the top and try to compile. Should work for you now.

Also look into rpetrich's theos fork. You should find the libsubstrate.dylib there